# Importance of going to university in the 21st century? [moved to meta]

Tags: discussion

The question https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9794/importance-of-going-to-university-in-the-21st-century was closed on the main site, and identified as non-constructive, although it has received 5 different answers.

How could this question be changed to be more constructive?

Comment: This could work in chat or a special chat room...

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Suggest some none stackexchange communities. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to suggest how could this question be changed to be more constructive?

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't think this question can be transformed into one that fits the Q&A format of Ac.SE. It's an interesting discussion topic, but it does not seem that any objective answer can be provided. As eykanal pointed out, there are many other places for discussions, and Ac.SE is just not one of them.

Hence, I think this question should be removed if not edited, since as a general rule, closed questions are destined to be either edited and reopened or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an alternative location for discussion, there are a number of places you can try:

- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) allows questions of any type and has a large user base.
- The [Chronicle forums](http://chronicle.com/forums/) may be a good place, but it may be off-topic there.
- You can try to bring it up on the relevant communities on Reddit. I'm not going to link to specific subreddits as I'm not familiar with them, but there are many that deal with universities, colleges, and higher education.

Comment: suggest subtopicforums on quora and chronicle

Comment: Not sure, as I'm not a frequent visitor to either site. Check both sites out, poke around the FAQs, and post wherever it seems most appropriate. Best of luck!